# Equality of two sets from homogenous differential equation solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, elementary-set-theory

I'm currently having a very specific difficulty for the end of the proof of this theorem about homogenous differential equation solutions :

> Let $a$ be a continuous function over some interval $I$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with values within $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.
>
> The solutions to the homogenous differential equation $(E_h):y'+ay=0$ over $I$ are the functions of the form $Cf_0$, with $f_0$ any non-zero solution to $(E_h)$ over $I$, and $C\in\mathbb{K}$.

After finding the set of solutions to $(E_h)$ to be $S_h=\{Cf_1, C\in\mathbb{K}\}$ (for $f_1$ some convenient function), we have to prove we can pick any of these functions to build the whole set of solutions.

The documentation i'm using proves it like so :

> If $f_0$ is any non-zero solution to $(E_h)$, then $\exists C_0\in\mathbb{K}^*/f_0=C_0f_1$.
>
> But then, $S_h=\{Cf_1,C\in\mathbb{K}\}=\{\frac{C}{C_0}C_0f_1,C\in\mathbb{K}\}=\{\frac{C}{C_0}f_0,C\in\mathbb{K}\}\subset\{C'f_0,C'\in\mathbb{K}\}$
>
> and $\{Cf_0, C\in\mathbb{K}\}=\{CC_0f_1,C\in\mathbb{K}\}\subset\{C'f_1,C'\in\mathbb{K}\}$
>
> Eventually : $S_h=\{Cf_0,C\in\mathbb{K}\}$

Even though i completely understand that to prove that two sets are equal, mutual inclusion is a common technique, i thought one could directly write :

> $S_h=\{Cf_1,C\in\mathbb{K}\}=\{\frac{C}{C_0}C_0f_1,C\in\mathbb{K}\}=\{\frac{C}{C_0}f_0,C\in\mathbb{K}\}=\{C'f_0,C'\in\mathbb{K}\}$

and conclude in one line.

Either i don't see something very subtle, or the person who wrote this proof down went an extra mile.

Any clarifications ?
Thanks in advance, and cheers !